# How to import my dbc file to CAPL Browser?

Tags: capl

I am writing a code in a new .can file and it is not recognizing my messages that I have in my pre-defined dbc file. How can I point the CAPL browser to my dbc file? Should I use my CANoe configuration somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a node in my Simulation Setup in CANoe where I have already added my networks and dbc files. 
So right click on Nodes and the network explorer and click on "Insert...". Then under Node specification select File and select the .can file that you have written in CAPL and saved in your system. I have written the file previously in the Vector CAPL browser and saved it.

Comment: Note to self: sometimes when you open the .can file directly in the Vector CAPL Browser tool, you cannot see the messages and signal names in Symbols. When this happens go to your CANoe simulation setup and find that .can node you have added to your setup and click on the tiny edit button on the ECU so that the CAPL Browser links your .can file to your configuration and imports the database for you to easily drag and drop the signals to your code in CAPL Browser.

Answer (score 0):

CAPL .can source files get linked to a database and dll libraries only if they are opened through the Simulation Configuration (in CANoe) of which they are part of.

Or, you can open them separately from Windows, open the CANoe configuration, then press the Import CANoe/CANalyzer Environment button in the CAPL toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

press the Import CANoe/CANalyzer Environment button   great

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).